# Story identification: short story about an elevator that takes a rider to hell

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember it as a whimsical story, in which a naughty child pushes all the elevator button and it takes the child to "hell" as punishment. Because of this, I apologize to elevators whenever I make a mistake and wind up pushing multiple superfluous buttons.

Comment: Should we make this a [feature-request] to Otis, do you think?

Comment: I wrote a story similar to that while I was in high school.  The elevator took you to different levels of hell, sort of like Dante's Inferno.  It was a terrible story.

Comment: Funny, gentlemen!

Comment: The elevator in http://www.xkcd.com/288/ could probably take you to hell.  See also http://www.xkcd.com/1330/ which is not an elevator but might take you to hell.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, this stuck in my head for more than thirty years... have a look at this story: *Josie and the Elevator*, from the May 1980 edition of *Omni* magazine.

https://archive.org/stream/omni-magazine-1980-05/OMNI_1980_05#page/n1/mode/2up

Spoilt girl, prone to outbursts of temper, is taken to a sort of hell which is a corrupted version of her own life, after damaging the most precious possession of a sentient elevator in her apartment complex.

> She spends many years in hell without recollection of her former life, and finally returns to Earth after getting a chance to make amends with the elevator.